# Serial Numbering an SSRS Table with Grouping And Headers

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

[Report Design]

[image]

Here is an Example for a report that I am working on.
It is grouped by "CostCenter" Field and above each group there is a header with the SUM of the "Betrag" Field.
I want to Number each Column in the Table with the Headers as well.
I tried using `RowNumber(Nothing)` or `Row Number("DataSet")` Or `Running Value`.

I get these results [Report View]

[image]

I think there should be a way or a Formula that connects both Fields in the Colmun Row Number or "Zeilennr" that results with a Correct Row Numbering for each Row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost do this. The number would not work if placed to the left of the inner group, it needs to be at the same level as the details group but it will give you the correct number. I've only done very limited testing but it seems to work.

Go to the report's properties and then to the code tab.

Now add the following custom code function

```
Public rn as Integer

Public Function GetRn() AS Integer
    rn = rn +1
    return rn
End Function
```

Now in the text box where you want the number to appear use the expression

=Code.GetRn

All this does in increment the public variable by 1 then return it. It has no concept of the row it lies on, so if you did not include this on a group row, the numbers would remain sequential.

Here is a demo based on a small test report I had..

Design showing the position of the expression

[image]

Gives this result

[image]

Add the same expression to more text boxes...

[image]

Give these results...

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed explanation, it has worked as I wanted it to